# Upgrade GWT from 2.4.0 to 2.9.0 with GWT Plugins

Tags: java, gwt

I was trying to upgrade my GWT for one of project I have and already change the eclipse version and use the compatible version with the GWT Plugin because the old project still has the Google Plugins for Eclipse. The problem with the one I try to change; it keeps popping this out when I tried to change the SDK of the GWT:

[Progress Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiSHL.png)

From here I change the GWT version and click apply but it stays as version 2.4.0 before the progress show the above screenshot description. Anyone have any idea on why I cannot change the GWT version?

[GWT Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsymr.png)